# Rendering of cloze questions in pdf with r/exams

Tags: r-exams

I am trying to use `r/exams` to produce questions in pdf for a written exam.
I would like that `##ANSWERn##` in cloze questions is rendered in the pdf file, as follows:

1. a `num` question with a space:

   ```
   The unit price is ________.
   ```
2. a `schoice` question with boxes:

   ```
   [  ] Yes    [  ] No
   ```

   or something similar.

However, it seems that `##ANSWERn##` is not rendered at all in the pdf file and I couldn't find any documentation or example on how to change this.

Comment: Good idea, currently this cannot be done easily with the ANSWERi tags. I will have a look whether I can add support for it, though.

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to do, I think. Do you have a special LaTeX construct in mind for the blanks to fill in? Should it just be an underline of a certain length or should also the height be modified so that there is more space to write?

Comment: I thought of something like `\rule{0pt}{1.5\baselineskip}\rule[-3pt]{8ex}{.5pt}` where the `1.5\baselineskip` takes care of the height, and `8ex` is the horizontal length. I think something similar could be done for the HTML output

Comment: OK, thanks, will have a look. For HTML there is probably relatively little need for \_static\_ HTML - which would need to be printed - as PDF is usually more convenient for that. And for \_interactive\_ HTML we are currently working on `exams2webexercises` which can produce exercises like these: https://www.zeileis.org/quiz.html